# Error: must declare the scalar variable @newsSummary

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have declared `@newsSummary` as far as I am aware, but I still get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@newsSummmary".

I am trying to setup a news system, with images. I have most definitely also declared it in my HTML too.

Here is my C#

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  

            // Save files to disk
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/admin/news/" +  FileName));

            // Add Entry to DataBase
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles (FileName, FilePath) values(@FileName, @FilePath)" + "insert into tblNews (newsTitle, newsDate, newsSummmary, newsContent) values(@newsTitle, @newsDate, @newsSummmary, @newsContent)"; 

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "/images/admin/news/" + FileName);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsTitle", txtnewstitle.Text);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsDate", txtnewsdate.Text);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsSummary", txtnewssummary.Text);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsContent", txtnewsmaincontent.Text);            

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            try {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra m in the insert command `@newsSummmary`

Comment: @juharr oops! *hides away* - that's a sign I need to take a break. Well spotted, many thanks!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run two sql commands using the same SqlCommand.CommandText you need to separate the two commands with a semicolon

```
string strQuery = @"insert into tblFiles (FileName, FilePath) 
                    values(@FileName, @FilePath);
                    insert into tblNews (newsTitle, newsDate, newsSummmary, newsContent) 
                    values(@newsTitle, @newsDate, @newsSummmary, @newsContent)";
```

Thanks to Juharr below because he noted the problem that triggers the exact error message being the extra (or missing) `m` in the name `@newSummmary`.
It is not clear if you have really a field named `Summmary` with 3 m but you could fix the problem removing the extra m from your query or adding the extra m to your parameter.

This should be closed as a simple typo, however the error about the missing semicolon between the two command texts is still there and will bite you at the next step.

Comment: The real problem is the extra "m" in the parameter name.

Comment: oops, that's true, however without the semicolon he will get the error at the next step